# How to navigate back to previous route/page in different tab in Angular7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have multiple tabs in my angular7 app. And I need to navigate back from one page to different page.

Scenario: I have a search page in Tab1 , once we search with any search string got search results,  now if I click on any one of record from among results list I am taking user to different page (page2) which is in different tab ( Tab 2). Now the challenge am facing is to navigate back to previous page and I have to preserve the original user search results on that page..

Tab A --> page1 --> link button on page 1 redirects to page2 --> if i click on back button ( anchor tag) on page2 , i need to go back to previous route (page1) and search results should be preserve.

Please let me know your inputs..

Comment: U can use sessionStorage or localStorage  and store user navigation activities there.

Answer (score 0):

If I imagine perfectly, There is a solution that your tab mechanism is not fit for this problem.

Instead of using two different HTML component, use one single component and let users navigate between tabs, not pages.

I solve this problem with Angular Material's `<mat-table>`.

in `.ts` file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tab-group-basic-example',
  templateUrl: 'tab-group-basic-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab-group-basic-example.css'],
})
export class MyComponent {
// activate or deactivate tabs..
}
```

in `HTML`:

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="First">

        <!-- My search and result page html here -->

    </mat-tab>

    <mat-tab label="Second">
        <!-- My second page content here -->
    </mat-tab>

 </mat-tab-group>
```

For additional research [click Angular Material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview)